# Total hit/visitor counter in ASP.NET Core MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to count total ever hit/visitor in my ASP.NET Core Web application. Whenever a new visitor will come to my site, total ever visitor value will be increased by one in database.

In case of traditional ASP.NET MVC Application we can solve the problem by using Session variable in *Session_Star()* method in the *global.asax* file.

What would be the best option to do so in ASP.NET Core MVC? Or how can I track whenever a new visitor will come to my site?

**Any appropriate solution will highly be appreciated. Thanks!**

Comment: is this `total current live sessions` or the `total sessions ever to hit the site`? For example, if the total current live sessions, i'm sure you could get this value from Google Analytics?

Comment: Currently I need total sessions ever to hit the site. But it will be useful if I get the both total current live sessions and the total sessions ever to hit the site.

Comment: OK, so GA will should allow you to extract the 'live user' count via their API. You could probably also get a total sessions for all time from GA too.

Comment: I shall store the total ever visitor count to database..so is there no way to track whenever a new user will come to my site?

Comment: I'm sure there is....ok, very simple idea (which is flawed) but you could increment the count in the db for each user to hit the site then set a cookie in their browser with a 'datetime visited' value maybe? You could then  look for this value, work on a pre-determined 'expiry' time and either wipe the cookie, increment the counter and re-add it or skip it depending on the datetime in the cookie.

Comment: Yes! you got it..absolutely I want that..I just need to  know whenever a new visitor is come to my site..but I shall use GUID instead of datatime..

Comment: that will work...to an extent but it is flawed by the 'expiry' you decide on and the fact cookies can be wiped. if that is accurate enough though I'm happy to have been of assistance!

Comment: Cookie will be wipe out automatically on visitor session close

Comment: There is still a way to [use Sessions in ASP.NET MVC Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.0) and you could easily extend the middleware to increment the counter when a Session Variable is not set yet, which you then set (even a simple `bool counted = true` is sufficient)

Comment: I already told that in my question..I want a different option

Comment: Yes but in the end, you'll end up checking _something_ on every single subsequent request anyway

Comment: @thmsh, Yes! you are right..I have already done this and I shall post it as answer to this question soon..Thanks for you suggestion

Comment: Dear commenters ! Thanks for your efforts.Please take a look I have done it and posted it as answer to this question..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay! I have solved the problem using ASP.NET Core Middleware and session as below:

**Here is the Middleware component:**

```
public class VisitorCounterMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _requestDelegate;

    public VisitorCounterMiddleware(RequestDelegate requestDelegate)
    {
        _requestDelegate = requestDelegate;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
      string visitorId = context.Request.Cookies["VisitorId"];
      if (visitorId == null)
      {
         //don the necessary staffs here to save the count by one

         context.Response.Cookies.Append("VisitorId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), new CookieOptions()
            {
                    Path = "/",
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Secure = false,
            });
       }

      await _requestDelegate(context);
    }
}
```

**Finally in the Startup.cs file:**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseMiddleware(typeof(VisitorCounterMiddleware));
}
```

Comment: How can i use this class in controller?

Comment: @saeed, Tell what exactly do you need?

Comment: I want to get total unique visitors in asp.net core 2. I created class `VisitorCounterMiddleware` and add `middleware` in `startup.cs` similar to the answer. Now how can i use this class?  what is `RequestDelegate` parameter?

Comment: @saeed You if you did as exactly as in the answer then you don't need anymore thing to do. Now put a break point on the `VisitorCounterMiddleware` class and run the application on debug mode and see what happened!

Comment: Please help how can I use It.

Comment: Just do what exactly has been described in the answer!

Comment: `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;` must add this packge for `RequestDelegate` @topcool

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution (ASP.Net Core 2.2 MVC);

First you need to catch the remote ip of the visitor. To achieve that, put this code to your startup configure services method:

```
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options => options.ForwardedHeaders = 
    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto);
```

then in your default end point (mine is home/index), get the ip of the visitor with this:

```
string remoteIpAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString();

            if (Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-For"))
            { 
                remoteIpAddress = Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
            }
```

After getting the remote ip, you can save it to your database if this is it's first visit. You can create a simple model for that, like mine:

```
    public class IPAdress:BaseModel
    {
        public string ClientIp { get; set; }
        public int? CountOfVisit { get; set; }
    }
```

if it is not the first visit of the client, then simply increase the CountOfVisit property value. You have to do all of those at client's first request to your default end point. Avoid dublication.

Finally, you can write custom methods matching your needs.